# SSRS Conditional Formatting on Row Group

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a report that groups on Income, Non Payroll Expenditure and Payroll. Within each group there are separate rows for different categories.

I'd like to have a conditional formatting where if the YTD Variance column total <0, then its red, and if its >0 its green. I've tried numerous methods (Iif and Switch) but cannot get it to work.

This is the current expression I've got on background color.

```
=IIf(Fields!YTD_Variance.Value<0,"#fd6969","#54b322")
```

As can be seen in the image its not working correctly. Both of The YTD Variance totals should be red.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the total is an aggregate, something like `=SUM(Fields!TYD_Variance.Value)` then this is what you need to be evaluating.

Change your expression so that is compares the summed value, so something like this...

```
=IIf(SUM(Fields!YTD_Variance.Value) < 0, "#fd6969", "#54b322")
```

Comment: That's great. Can you please mark the answer as accepted. This helps other SO users when looking for similar answers.